# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, port

I am trying to install Apache Tomcat server 7.0 in Eclipse Indigo OS-Windows server 2013, while I am starting the server, I am encounter the following error:

I am new to Eclipse, and do not know how to solve this problem, please help me.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:703)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
```

Comment: `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind` - Do you have another Server running at port 8005?

Comment: check your ports, 8005 is used by some other application.

Comment: I changed the port number to 8010 even the error is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ports are already in use.
change the port number in server setting(double click on server) from Eclipse.

replace "8" by "9" ... if your port is 8005 replace it by 9005.

Answer (score 1):

Open Powershell and type

```
netstat -an
```

to see which ports are in use.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you did not launch the server twice since both instances are using same port.